How to sort a list with specified order?
OrderEntry Object:
@Data
public static class OrderEntry {
    private String entryNumber;
    // giftFlag=0 means the orderEntry is a normal entry
    // giftFlag=1 means the orderEntry is a gift entry
    private Integer giftFlag;
    private List<String> sourceEntryNumbers;
}

giftFlag=0 means the orderEntry is a normal entry
giftFlag=1 means the orderEntry is a gift entry
I have a list of orderEntry, it contains normal entry and gift entry. Now I want to sort the orderEntry list with specified order, normal entry firstly, if this normal entry have gift entry, then gift entry secondly.
update:
What I want to sort is ordering the non-gift by entryNumber and tailing the gifts.
It's not the multiple fields sort and can not use Comparator's compare and thenComparing methods
How to sort this list? Any help?
@Test
public void testSort() {
    OrderEntry orderEntry1 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry1.setEntryNumber("1");
    orderEntry1.setGiftFlag(0);
    OrderEntry orderEntry2 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry2.setEntryNumber("2");
    orderEntry2.setGiftFlag(0);
    OrderEntry orderEntry3 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry3.setGiftFlag(1);
    // it means this gift orderEntry created from orderEntry1 and orderEntry2
    orderEntry3.setSourceEntryNumbers(Arrays.asList("1", "2"));

    OrderEntry orderEntry4 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry4.setEntryNumber("3");
    orderEntry4.setGiftFlag(0);
    OrderEntry orderEntry5 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry5.setGiftFlag(1);
    // it means this gift orderEntry created from orderEntry3
    orderEntry5.setSourceEntryNumbers(Arrays.asList("3"));

    OrderEntry orderEntry6 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry6.setEntryNumber("4");
    orderEntry6.setGiftFlag(0);
    OrderEntry orderEntry7 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry7.setGiftFlag(1);
    // it means this gift orderEntry created from orderEntry3
    orderEntry7.setSourceEntryNumbers(Arrays.asList("4"));

    OrderEntry orderEntry8 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry8.setEntryNumber("8");
    orderEntry8.setGiftFlag(0);

    List<OrderEntry> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(orderEntry1);
    list.add(orderEntry2);
    list.add(orderEntry4);
    list.add(orderEntry6);
    list.add(orderEntry3);
    list.add(orderEntry5);
    list.add(orderEntry7);
    list.add(orderEntry8);

    System.out.println(JSON.toJSONString(list));
    // output:
    // [{"entryNumber":"1","giftFlag":0},{"entryNumber":"2","giftFlag":0},{"entryNumber":"3","giftFlag":0},{"entryNumber":"4","giftFlag":0},{"giftFlag":1,"sourceEntryNumbers":["1","2"]},{"giftFlag":1,"sourceEntryNumbers":["3"]},{"giftFlag":1,"sourceEntryNumbers":["4"]},{"entryNumber":"8","giftFlag":0}]

    // expected output:
    // [{"entryNumber":"1","giftFlag":0},{"entryNumber":"2","giftFlag":0},{"giftFlag":1,"sourceEntryNumbers":["1","2"]},{"entryNumber":"3","giftFlag":0},{"giftFlag":1,"sourceEntryNumbers":["3"]},{"entryNumber":"4","giftFlag":0},{"giftFlag":1,"sourceEntryNumbers":["4"]},{"entryNumber":"8","giftFlag":0}]
}


"and can not use Comparator's compare and thenComparing methods" - why not? That's exactly what they're there for.

There are normal entry and gift entry in the list object, but gift entry has  extra sourceEntryNumbers  property, it means the gift entry created from which normal entry. For example, buy one, get one free

And I want to sort the list with normal entry, gift entry order. The orginal list like: normalEntry1, normalEntry2, normalEntry3, giftEntry1, giftEntry3, and expected order list like: normalEntry1, giftEntry1, normalEntry2, normalEntry3, giftEntry3.....

Your problem is, that you don't want to sort them purely by comparing them in pairs but by ordering the non-gift orders by entryNumber and tailing the gifts. But I still don't understand your example in the post. You expect orderEntry3 to come after orderEntry1 and orderEntry2.

Do you want to enqueue the gifts directly after the highest mentioned normal entry?

This Question is not much better than your original attempt.

@ValerijDobler Yes, by ordering the non-gift orders by entryNumber and tailing the gifts.

@Holinc check out my answer. Does this achieve what you are looking for?

If I understood you correctly, you want the gift orders to follow the highest normal orders they reference.
Then we can add a method to either return the entryNumber or the last sourceEntry and use this in the compareTo method. Also we need to sort then by the giftFlag, because we want entryNumber "2" to come before the sourceEntryNumbers List.of("1", "2).
@Data
public class OrderEntry implements Comparable<OrderEntry>{
    private String entryNumber;
    // giftFlag=0 means the orderEntry is a normal entry
    // giftFlag=1 means the orderEntry is a gift entry
    private Integer giftFlag;
    private List<String> sourceEntryNumbers;

    // can be omitted, it you know that the sourceEntryNumbers are sorted already
    public void setSourceEntryNumbers(List<String> sourceEntryNumbers) {
        this.sourceEntryNumbers = sourceEntryNumbers.stream().sorted().toList();
    }

    private String getEntryNumberForSorting() {
        if (entryNumber != null)
        //if (giftFlag == 1) // alternatively
        {
            return entryNumber;
        }
        //return sourceEntryNumbers.getLast(); // since java 21
        return sourceEntryNumbers.get(sourceEntryNumbers.size() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(OrderEntry o) {
        return Comparator.comparing(OrderEntry::getEntryNumberForSorting)
                .thenComparing(OrderEntry::getGiftFlag)
                .compare(this, o);
    }
}

and then you can sort them e.g. like
final var orderedOrders = orders.stream()
                .sorted()
                .toList();


An elegant way to solve my problem. I post my answer by adding sortIndex field to solve it. Could you help me to look it works well?

As I mentioned below your answer, it wouldn't work. It would sort the gift order occasionally into a different location than how you mentioned in the question that you would want it to.

You say you cannot use comparing and thenComparing, but you can. The function you provide doesn't need to be a method reference.
Assuming that giftFlag is not nullable, and entryNumber is not nullable for gift entries:
Comparator<OrderEntry> entryComparator = Comparator.comparing(OrderEntry::getGiftFlag)
        .thenComparing(entry -> entry.getGiftFlag() == 1 ? entry.getEntryNumber() : "");

This will let normal entries come before gift entries. Each normal entry will then get the same result for the second comparison, which is fine as long as you don't start using TreeSet. The result is that normal entries come first, in their original order, followed by gift entries ordered by entry number.
Alternatively, you can use a regular comparator:
Comparator<OrderEntry> entryComparator = (entry1, entry2) -> {
    int result = entry1.getGiftFlag().compareTo(entry2.getGiftFlag());
    if (result == 0 && entry1.getGiftFlag() == 1) {
        // entry2.getGiftFlag() == 1 as well
        result = entry1.getEntryNumber().compareTo(entry2.getEntryNumber());
    }
    // else both have getGiftFlag() == 0, or they have different gift flags
    return result;
}


An unrelated piece of advice: use an enum for giftFlag. GiftFlag.NORMAL is clearer than 0.
public enum GiftFlag {
    NORMAL,
    GIFT,
}


There are normal entry and gift entry in the list object, but gift entry has extra sourceEntryNumbers property, it means the gift entry created from which normal entry. For example, buy one, get one free. And I want to sort the list with normal entry, gift entry order. The orginal list like: normalEntry1, normalEntry2, normalEntry3, giftEntry1, giftEntry3, and expected order list like: normalEntry1, giftEntry1, normalEntry2, normalEntry3, giftEntry3.....

It does'n work in my case.

You can add compareTo function in your OrderEntry class.
public static class OrderEntry implements Comparable<OrderEntry> {
    private String entryNumber;
    // giftFlag=0 means the orderEntry is a normal entry
    // giftFlag=1 means the orderEntry is a gift entry
    private Integer giftFlag;
    private List<String> sourceEntryNumbers;
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(OrderEntry other) {
        return Integer.compare(this.giftFlag, other.giftFlag);
    }
}

@Test
public void testSort() {
    ...

    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println(JSON.toJSONString(list));
}


It's not what I want.

I try my way as below. Adding sortIndex field to sort.
@Test
public void testSort() {
    OrderEntry orderEntry1 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry1.setEntryNumber("1");
    orderEntry1.setGiftFlag(0);
    OrderEntry orderEntry2 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry2.setEntryNumber("2");
    orderEntry2.setGiftFlag(0);
    OrderEntry orderEntry3 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry3.setGiftFlag(1);
    // it means this gift orderEntry created from orderEntry1 and orderEntry2
    orderEntry3.setSourceEntryNumbers(Arrays.asList("1", "2"));

    OrderEntry orderEntry4 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry4.setEntryNumber("3");
    orderEntry4.setGiftFlag(0);
    OrderEntry orderEntry5 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry5.setGiftFlag(1);
    // it means this gift orderEntry created from orderEntry3
    orderEntry5.setSourceEntryNumbers(Arrays.asList("3"));

    OrderEntry orderEntry6 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry6.setEntryNumber("4");
    orderEntry6.setGiftFlag(0);
    OrderEntry orderEntry7 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry7.setGiftFlag(1);
    // it means this gift orderEntry created from orderEntry3
    orderEntry7.setSourceEntryNumbers(Arrays.asList("4"));

    OrderEntry orderEntry8 = new OrderEntry();
    orderEntry8.setEntryNumber("8");
    orderEntry8.setGiftFlag(0);

    List<OrderEntry> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(orderEntry1);
    list.add(orderEntry2);
    list.add(orderEntry4);
    list.add(orderEntry6);
    list.add(orderEntry3);
    list.add(orderEntry5);
    list.add(orderEntry7);
    list.add(orderEntry8);

    System.out.println(JSON.toJSONString(list));

    // setting value into sortIndex field
    list.forEach(item -> {
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(item.getSourceEntryNumbers())) {
            List<String> sourceEntryNumbers = item.getSourceEntryNumbers().stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            item.setSortIndex(sourceEntryNumbers.get(0));
        } else {
            item.setSortIndex(item.getEntryNumber());
        }
    });

    // sorting by sortIndex field again
    List<OrderEntry> result = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(OrderEntry::getSortIndex)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    // output result
    System.out.println(JSON.toJSONString(result));
}

@Data
public static class OrderEntry {
    private String entryNumber;
    private Integer giftFlag;
    private List<String> sourceEntryNumbers;

    // add sortIndex field to sort
    private String sortIndex;
}


If you choose sourceEntryNumbers.get(0) as your index, you would sort orderEntry3 before or after orderEntry2, which is also sub optimal.

It should work, I have already sorted sourceEntryNumbers with Comparator.reverseOrder()
List<String> sourceEntryNumbers = item.getSourceEntryNumbers().stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());

In this case, it worked by accident. Just try it with a reverse ordered List: orderEntry8,orderEntry7,orderEntry6,orderEntry5,orderEntry4,orderEntry3,orderEntry2,orderEntry1, then you'll see that at index 1 there will be orderEntry3 although you would expect orderEntry2 followed by orderEntry3, not the other way around.

This is why you need the .thenComparing(OrderEntry::getGiftFlag) part.
